# Is Lanyon - SalesForce.com integration publically available?

Tags: integration, appexchange

I want to integrate [Lanyon](http://www.lanyon.com/News/NewsViewer.aspx?RCID=8b84f6de-063e-4a28-9894-f4fed80e3c8a) with SalesForce.com. I see this news talking about the integration, but there is no such app in the App Exchange.

Anyone how this integration can be done. Is it a customization Lanyon does for its customers?

Answer (score 3):

This is a pretty specific question regarding Lanyon, and very few if any of us on SSE have probably even heard of it prior to this question, including myself.

That being said, I would reach out to Lanyon support: http://www.lanyon.com/Contact/Default.aspx.  Send them an email, Call them, hound them on twitter until you get the answer you're looking for.

If it turns out their solution isn't publically available, chances are Lanyon has web services avaiable, with which custom / external integration solutions would work.